# Unit testing expired JWT token Bad "options.expiresIn" option the payload already has an "exp" property

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, jwt

I am trying to generate an already expired JWT token for testing purpose, but I can't figure out the right way to do it.

How do you manage expired time in unit tests ?

Here is my attempt so far :

```
it('should return a new token if expired', async () => {
      const candidateId = 1
      const oneHourLessFromNow = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) - 3600
      const payload = { sub: candidateId, exp: oneHourLessFromNow }
      const initialToken = jwtService.sign(payload)
      const decodedInitialToken = jwtService.decode(initialToken)
      console.log(decodedInitialToken)
      expect(jwtService.verify(initialToken)).toThrowError('TokenExpiredError')
    })
```

Console error :

```
● AuthService › refresh › should return a new token if expired

    Bad "options.expiresIn" option the payload already has an "exp" property.

      113 |       const oneHourLessFromNow = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) - 3600
      114 |       const payload = { sub: candidateId, exp: oneHourLessFromNow }
    > 115 |       const initialToken = jwtService.sign(payload)
          |                                       ^
      116 |       const decodedInitialToken = jwtService.decode(initialToken)
      117 |       console.log(decodedInitialToken)
      118 |       expect(jwtService.verify(initialToken)).toThrowError('TokenExpiredError')

      at Object.module.exports [as sign] (../node_modules/jsonwebtoken/sign.js:133:20)
      at JwtService.sign (../node_modules/@nestjs/jwt/dist/jwt.service.js:27:20)
      at Object.<anonymous> (auth/auth.service.spec.ts:115:39)

  console.error
    undefined

      44 |       return this.createToken(candidateId)
      45 |     } catch (e) {
    > 46 |       console.error(e)
         |               ^
      47 |       throw new HttpException(
      48 |         ResponseMessage.INVALID_CODE,
      49 |         HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN

      at AuthService.verifySmsCode (auth/auth.service.ts:46:15)

  console.log
    { sub: 1, iat: 1602496713, exp: 1602500313 }

      at AuthService.refresh (auth/auth.service.ts:59:13)
```

Comment: What makes you believe the error has anything to do with the passed time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by passing the expired time properly :

```
it('should return a new token if expired', async () => {
  const candidateId = 1
  const payload = { sub: candidateId }
  const initialToken = jwtService.sign(payload, { expiresIn: 0 })
  const decodedInitialToken = jwtService.decode(initialToken)
  console.log(decodedInitialToken)
  expect(jwtService.verify(initialToken)).toThrowError('TokenExpiredError')
})
```

https://github.com/nestjs/jwt/issues/1#issuecomment-591281569